# How to make a new (dynamic) tab be the active page

Tags: delphi, lazarus

I tagged both Lazarus and Delphi as both seem to be similar (100%) for everything I've done so far. But my dev platform is Lazarus.

I'm dynamically creating a tab sheet like this:

```
procedure TForm1.cmdTabButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  NewTab: TTabSheet;
begin
  NewTab := TTabSheet.Create(PageControl1);
  NewTab.PageControl:= PageControl1;
  NewTab.Caption:='hi';
//  NewTab.TabVisible:=true;
//  newtab.SetFocus;
end;
```

The last two lines in the procedure are commented. Without them the code works but the new tab is not the one on top. I have to click it for it to come on top.

But if I uncomment those two lines, the program crashes stating that an invisible object cannot have focus.

any advice on how this can be fixed?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set the `ActivePage` property of the page control. Like this:

```
PageControl.ActivePage := NewTab;
```

Comment: Thanks for this. But my issue is that since many tabs are created, I haven't got track of the tab sheets by name. So is there a way around it or should I somehow assign a name for each page?

Comment: @itsols: use a different variable for the tab you want to activate by code (instead of reusing NewTab), put them all in an array if you need to access them further on in code as well, anything goes, it is up to you really.

Comment: Or use their index and use ActivePageIndex, as I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: Thanks for all the inputs!

Comment: When you create the one that needs to be active, make it the active page. I don't think you need to set names, or even keep all the new pages in an array. But it all depends on your criterion for choosing the active page. Without that knowledge it's hard to give you a prescriptive solution.

Answer (score 3):

A PageControl has properties `ActivePage` and `ActivePageIndex`, which you can use for this. `ActivePage` is the most convenient one in this case, since you can just call

```
PageControl1.ActivePage := NewTab;
```